# Xamarin crossplatform, how to reliably send events from server to client

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, push-notification, signalr

I'm creating video chat (like skype, but for a specific type of companies) apps for Android and iOS using Xamarin. I'm wondering what the best approach is to handle the server to client communication, specifically when a call is coming, how do I fast and reliably contact the receiver ie client phone?

- I want to be able to contact my App even if it is closed
- I need to know if the message have gone through
- It has to be fast, preferably under 1 second

I've read about push notification and they can wake my app, but they are slow and no guarantee they will get through.

I've been looking into SignalR which are fast and reliable, but I can't quite see how to open my app.

Currently I'm thinking about setting a status wether or not the app is open. If it's open I'll use signalR else the caller will be asked if he wants to notify the receiver about the incoming call. Does anyone have better idea?

Comment: Using SignalR for streaming is not a good idea. It's not really designed for that.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about streaming, just to notify the client that there is a request so the client can call back and aquire the session information

Comment: OK. It was not clear to me from the post whether SignalR was supposed to be used only for notifications or notifications and streaming. If this is for notifications only then it sounds good. One thing I am not sure is "contact my App even if it is closed". SignalR requires the connection to be open and I am not sure how the connection is supposed to be open if the app is closed.

Comment: Thats exactly my issue... Are there any other way than notifications to get my app to open or could I create a service which is always connected through signalr?

Comment: I don't know much about programming for Android and/or iOS so can't help in this regard. Sorry.